# C# XML reading foreach always first value

Tags: c#, .net, xml

My XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <teklif>
 <bilgiler>
<firma>Firma Adı</firma>
<aciklama>Açıklama</aciklama>
<isim>Ad Soyad</isim>
<telefon>Telefon</telefon>
<eposta>E Posta</eposta>
<urunler>
  <urun>
    <resimDosyasi>Dosya Seçilmedi</resimDosyasi>
    <aciklama>Ürün Açıklaması</aciklama>
    <birim>3,00</birim>
    <miktar>1</miktar>
    <toplam>0,00</toplam>
  </urun>
  <urun>
    <resimDosyasi>Dosya Seçilmedi</resimDosyasi>
    <aciklama>Ürün Açıklaması</aciklama>
    <birim>5,00</birim>
    <miktar>1</miktar>
    <toplam>0,00</toplam>
  </urun>
  <urun>
    <resimDosyasi>Dosya Seçilmedi</resimDosyasi>
    <aciklama>aas</aciklama>
    <birim>2,00</birim>
    <miktar>1</miktar>
    <toplam>0,00</toplam>
  </urun>
</urunler>
```

And My Function which reads the XML file

```
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(filename);
        XmlNodeList xmllist = doc.SelectNodes("/teklif/bilgiler/urunler");
        foreach(XmlNode nod in xmllist)
        {
            foreach(XmlNode childNode in nod.ChildNodes)
            {
                // her ürünün childnode oldu

                    if(childNode.Name == "#text")
                    {
                    } else
                    {
                    var urun_resim = childNode.SelectSingleNode("//resimDosyasi").InnerText;
                    var urun_aciklama = childNode.SelectSingleNode("//aciklama").InnerText;
                    var urun_birim = childNode.SelectSingleNode("//birim").InnerText;
                    MessageBox.Show(urun_birim);
                    var urun_miktar = childNode.SelectSingleNode("//miktar").InnerText;
                    var urun_toplam = childNode.SelectSingleNode("//toplam").InnerText;
                    var urun = new Urun(urun_resim, urun_birim, urun_miktar, urun_aciklama);
                    lw_urunler.Items.Add(urun);

                    }
            }
        }
```

The problem is when I message box the //birim in foreach loop, it always writes the first one - 3,00((3 times). As you can see in XML, first is 3,00, the second is 5,00 and the third is 2,00 but it always writes the first one. I checked up a lot but I can't see the problem.

Answer (score 6):

Try it without the `//`, e.g. `childNode.SelectSingleNode("birim")`.  Two forward slashes mean the root of the XML document, and my guess is it's just always finding the first `birim` node starting from the root each time.

Answer (score 2):

The // means to select nodes no matter where they are under the current context. Current context defaults to the root. To limit the results to those under the current child node follow this pattern (just add a dot):

```
var urun_resim = childNode.SelectSingleNode(".//resimDosyasi").InnerText;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication52
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            List<urun> uruns = doc.Descendants("urun").Select(x => new urun() {
                resimDosyasi = (string)x.Element("resimDosyasi"),
                aciklama = (string)x.Element("aciklama"),
                birim = (string)x.Element("birim"),
                miktar = (int)x.Element("miktar"),
                toplam = (string)x.Element("toplam")
            }).ToList();

        }
    }
    public class urun
    {
        public string resimDosyasi { get; set; }
        public string aciklama { get; set; }
        public string birim { get; set; }
        public int miktar { get; set; }
        public string toplam { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach that would increase the readability and maintenance of your code would be to map the XML schema into an object model.

Doing so, you could easly load the XML data as follows:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Teklif));
using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open))
{
     Teklif result = (Teklif)serializer.Deserialize(fileStream);
}

// Object model example
[XmlRoot("teklif")]
public class Teklif
{
    [XmlElement()]
    public bilgiler bilgiler { get; set; }
}

public class bilgiler
{
    [XmlElement()] public string firma { get; set; }
    [XmlElement()] public string aciklama { get; set; }
    [XmlElement()] public string isim { get; set; }
    [XmlElement()] public string telefon { get; set; }
    [XmlElement()] public string eposta { get; set; }

    [XmlArray()]
    [XmlArrayItem("urun")]
    public List<Urun> urunler { get; set; }
}

public class Urun
{
    [XmlElement()] public string resimDosyasi { get; set; }
    [XmlElement()] public string aciklama { get; set; }
    [XmlElement()] public string birim { get; set; }
    [XmlElement()] public int miktar { get; set; }
    [XmlElement()] public string toplam { get; set; }
}
```